# Нарушение порядка ОЧ при повторяющихся союзах

Tags: грамматика, союзы, однородные-члены, порядок-слов

> То проедет трактор, то машина.

А действительно ли нельзя использовать такой порядок слов? Разве не может подразумеваться "то проедет трактор, то проедет машина"? (Да и вроде бы в речи такое часто можно услышать)

Comment: Вы сами объяснили причину.

Comment: Просто здесь это предложение представлено, как некорректное:
https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/240-upotreblenieodnorodnyhchlenov.html#:~:text=%D0%A2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0.

Comment: Они ниже пишут, что "но и" на "а и" нельзя заменять, а это абсолютно нормально.

Comment: *То он придёт, то она* — звучит нормально; *придёт то он, то она* — звучит плохо, даже как-то неправильно.

Comment: Союз "не только... а и" тоже существует: https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%E2%80%A6_%D0%B0_%D0%B8